# How can I execute a Python instruction once inside If statement

Tags: python, opencv

I'm updating a Python/OpenCV Face Recognition program, so when it recognizes a person, the name of the person and time, will be stored in google sheets. Please Check this code :

```py
    for x, y, w, h in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        if confidence > 0:

            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(confidence))

            sheet.append_row([str(id), strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())])

        else:
            id = "Inconnue"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(confidence))
```

So, I have the `sheet.append_row([str(id), strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())])` That I want to execute just once. When I execute the code, it keeps on sending my name to the Sheet while I'm facing the camera.

Comment: Break out of the loop after appending?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: As long as `confidence` has a value greater than `0` and the loop is rolling, the `sheet.append_row()` line will keep getting executed. You will have to guard against it by only appending rows that haven't already been added (based on whatever criteria differentiates one row from another).

Comment: How can i break the sheet.append_row() to execute just one time? Because now, it keeps on appending my name on the sheet.

Comment: Why do you have the `id = "Inconnue"` line? `id` is not used on the next loop and is overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a set of names you've already inserted i.e:

```py
existing_entries = {}   # set of existing entries
for x,y,w,h in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 2)
    id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

    if confidence > 0:


        id = names['id']
        if id not in existing_entries:
           confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(confidence))

           sheet.append_row([str(id), strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())])
           existing_entries.add(id)   # add recognized entry to existing entries 

    else:
        id = "Inconnue"
        confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(confidence))
```